# Emploi de 'ça roule' signifiant 'ça va' : régionalisme ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

J'ai entendu plusieurs fois des franciliens dire 'ça roule', voulant dire 'ça marche', 'ça va'. Est-ce que la tournure est un régionalisme ou pas ?

Comment: Régionalisme en quel sens? Seulement en Ile-de-France?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On trouve l'expression dans le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A7a_roule), et il n'est pas mentionné que ce soit un régionalisme.

> Locution interjective
>
> **ça roule** \sa ʁul\
>
> 1  (Familier) S'emploie pour exprimer son accord.
> — Tu veux pas aller acheter du pain ? Il n'y en a plus.
> — Ça roule !
> 2 (En tant que question) Ça va.
> 3  (En tant que réponse) Ça va.
> — Bonjour ma bichette, tu vas bien ?
> — Oui, je me caille les couilles en fumant, mais ça roule.
> — Oh, Crystal, ne parle pas comme ça...
> — Oui, je sais Maman, c'est pas féminin, blablabla. — (Laura Trompette, Ladies' Taste, éd. Hugo Roman, 2015)

Non, ce ne doit pas être considéré comme étant un régionalisme ; une raison assez solide en support de ce fait c'est que cette expression est utilisée dans les films.

Comment: C'est de l'argot et aussi utilisé par les jeunes et les hommes. Je vois mal une bourgeoise parisienne d'un certain âge disant sérieusement.  "Ça roule?" en arrivant à un rendez-vous avec une amie dans un café du sixième.

Comment: @Lambie Non, ce n'est pas de l'argot, et employé à propos des affaires c'est familier (TLFi : c) Fam. [Le suj. désigne des affaires, des entreprises hum.] Aller bien, réussir. Synon. marcher, aller comme sur des roulettes (v. roulette)). Mais comme vous l'employez, pour « ça va ? », je crois que c'est encore plus familier, et dénote bien une certaine vulgarité que vous semblez percevoir. Je ne comprend pas votre dernière phrase, l'idée que vous réfèreriez à une excuse suffisante pour indulger vous-même dans l'usage de cette expression,  cette excuse étant que l'anglophonie serait pitoyable.

Comment: Ouais: http://carfree.fr/index.php/2022/01/25/mobilite-ca-roule-pour-les-riches/ faut pas oublier les bagnolles. Le taux de motorisation des automobilistes est proportionnel à leur revenu: plus on est riche et plus on possède de voitures. //Ça roule ou pas? Oui, ma voiture roule sans problème. [ha ha]